# How should I do to decode % escaped japanese string in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, escaping

I want to decode % escaped string like below.

```
%E7%89%9B%E4%B9%B3%E3%81%8C%E7%BE%8E%E5
```

Through Web API, I get xml data that includes japanese string. This app received with NSURLConnection. So the data was received below method.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSString *xml = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:encoding];
    NSData *xmlData = [[xml stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:encoding]
                       dataUsingEncoding:encoding];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
}
```

However, this xmlData has only english alphabet strings not japanese escaped strings. So I cannot get japanese strings data from xmlData.

By all rights, this xmlData should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><ResultSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:yahoo:jp:jlp" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:yahoo:jp:jlp http://jlp.yahooapis.jp/MAService/V1/parseResponse.xsd"><ma_result><total_count>3</total_count><filtered_count>3</filtered_count><word_list><word><surface>夏</surface><reading>なつ</reading><pos>名詞</pos></word><word><surface>は</surface><reading>は</reading><pos>助詞</pos></word><word><surface>あつい</surface><reading>あつい</reading><pos>形容詞</pos></word></word_list></ma_result></ResultSet>
```

But now xmlData is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><ResultSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:yahoo:jp:jlp" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:yahoo:jp:jlp http://jlp.yahooapis.jp/MAService/V1_list></ma_result></ResultSet>
```

I think stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding method omit japanese data, doesn't it?
Please tell me how to do solve.